# MySQL with IFNULL in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL table with this row :

```
+----------+--------+------+-------+
| list_uid | sku    | qty  | verif |
+----------+--------+------+-------+
|       49 | 024522 | 10   | 8     |
+----------+--------+------+-------+
```

I try to select this row with this query :

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ae_rf_list_picked
WHERE
  `qty` != 0 AND
  IFNULL(`verif`, 0) < `qty` AND 
  `sku` = '024522' AND 
  `list_uid` = 49
```

I don't understand why this row is not return by this query.
If I remove this part

> IFNULL(`verif`, 0) < `qty` AND

the query return the row.

Comment: What are the column types? Quote manual: _"IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used."_ Now, if you go into that with `'8'` (instead of `8`), you are checking `'8' < '10'`, and that is of course not true, because string comparison works character-by-character, from the left.

Comment: If you using strings instead of integers, you need to understand that `'8'` comes ***after*** `'10'`...

Comment: Here is SQL fiddle, if columns are integers everything works correctly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34c39c/1

Comment: If you EVER need to do math on it, store it as a number. If you'll NEVER do math on it store it as string. If it needs to do both, you need two columns.  The left justification of qty and verif seem to imply they are text

Comment: Ok thank you! Like you said the field type of qty and verif was TINYTEXT. I understand what I need to do but I dont understand why 8 comes after 10.

Comment: _"but I dont understand why 8 comes after 10"_ - because, as said, strings are compared character-by-character, from left to right. Is `ABC` greater than `ABB`? We look at the first characters A=A, can't decide, second characters B=B, can't decide, 3rd characters C>B - so yes, `ABC` is greater than `ABB`. And now the same thing, with `8` and `10`: We check the first _characters_ of both of those _strings_ - `8` is greater than `1`, so we are done here, and have determined that `'8' > '10'`

Comment: Very good thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need to cast verif and qty to numeric values

Assuming no decimals and < 10 characters...

```
SELECT *
FROM ae_rf_list_picked
WHERE `qty` != 0 
  AND cast(IFNULL(`verif`, 0) as Numeric(10)) < cast(`qty` as numeric(10))  
  AND `sku` = '024522' 
  AND `list_uid` = 49
```